# ActionBar is not shown in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am following udacity to course to learn android developement. when I run the app on emulator, `action bar` is not shown.

I have another activity which is triggered by the main activity. If I do not add following line in `android_manifest` file then when clicking on listview in main activity gives me following error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

So I googled this error and I got that `App-Compat` should be used.
So I added this following line in `android_manifest` file

```
<application
....
....
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
>.....</application>
```

So after adding this line I get following screen which has no action bar. 
[image: ScreenShot]

**When I remove the line in `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat` `manifest` file, I get Action bar but after clicking the list view gives me that error**

*EDIT*

This is my styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

*EDIT*

My manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.suraj.sunshine">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".DetailedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detailed"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.suraj.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detailed"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.suraj.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you searched your `Error`

Comment: What are you extending in the `Activity` class

Comment: @Trivial I am extending FragmentActivity class

Comment: pls show style file `"@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Try to use `AppCompatActivity` instead

Comment: @mdtuyen question updated with styles.xml file

Comment: add your whole manifest file here

Comment: @Bhargav manifest file added. Please see the edited post

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your Manifest.

//use **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"** Instead of **android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"**

```
<application
    ....
    ....
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >.....</application>
```

Comment: No this just made my screen background white color

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `style.xml`:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
```

And in manifest:

```
<application android:theme ="@style/AppTheme"> 

</application>
```

Hope it helps.